# Loop and crawler items and save elements as json format in Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Given a link from [here](https://wh.lianjia.com/ershoufang/jiangan/):

[image]

I would like to loop all the counties and then all commercial districts, the save them as a txt file with json format as follows:

```
{"\u5317\u8521": "/ershoufang/beicai/", "\u78a7\u4e91": "/ershoufang/biyun/", "\u66f9\u8def": "/ershoufang/caolu/", "\u5ddd\u6c99": "/ershoufang/chuansha/", "\u5927\u56e2\u9547": "/ershoufang/datuanzhen/", ...}
```

How could I do that? Thanks at advance.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = 'https://wh.lianjia.com/ershoufang/jiangan/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
text = soup.find_all(text=True)

# xpath for counties
# counties: /html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/dl[2]/dd/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]
# /html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/dl[2]/dd/div[1]/div[1]/a[2]
# /html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/dl[2]/dd/div[1]/div[1]/a[3]

# xpath for commercial districts
# /html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/dl[2]/dd/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]
# /html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/dl[2]/dd/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```py
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://wh.lianjia.com"
start_url = f"{base_url}/ershoufang/jiangan/"


def get_page(url: str) -> bytes:
    return requests.get(url).content


def make_soup(page: bytes) -> BeautifulSoup:
    return BeautifulSoup(
        page, "html.parser",
    ).find(
        "div",
        {"data-role": "ershoufang"},
    )


def find_anchors(soup: BeautifulSoup, div_num: int) -> list:
    return soup.find_all("div")[div_num].find_all("a")


countries = [
    f"{base_url}{a['href']}" for a
    in find_anchors(make_soup(get_page(start_url)), div_num=0)
]

districts = {}
for country in countries:
    print(f"Fetching data for {country}")
    districts.update(
        {
            a.getText(): a["href"]
            for a in find_anchors(make_soup(get_page(country)), div_num=1)
        }
    )

with open("all_districts.json", "w") as jf:
    json.dump(districts, jf, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Output:

```
{
    "CBD\u897f\u5317\u6e56": "/ershoufang/cbdxibeihu/",
    "\u4e03\u91cc\u5e99": "/ershoufang/qilimiao/",
    "\u4e09\u73af\u5357": "/ershoufang/sanhuannan/",
    "\u4e09\u9633\u8def": "/ershoufang/sanyanglu/",
    "\u4e1c\u6e56\u4e1c\u4ead": "/ershoufang/donghudongting/",
    "\u4e1c\u897f\u6e56\u5176\u5b83": "/ershoufang/dongxihuqita/",
    "\u4e2d\u5317\u8def": "/ershoufang/zhongbeilu/",
    "\u4e2d\u5357\u4e01\u5b57\u6865": "/ershoufang/zhongnandingziqiao/",
    "\u4e2d\u6cd5\u751f\u6001\u57ce": "/ershoufang/zhongfashengtaicheng/",
    "\u4e8c\u4e03": "/ershoufang/erqi2/",
    "\u5149\u8c37\u4e1c": "/ershoufang/guanggudong/",
    "\u5149\u8c37\u5357": "/ershoufang/guanggunan/",
    "\u5149\u8c37\u5e7f\u573a": "/ershoufang/guangguguangchang/",
    "\u5173\u5c71\u5927\u9053": "/ershoufang/guanshandadao/",
    "\u5173\u897f\u957f\u804c": "/ershoufang/guanxichangzhi/",
    "\u524d\u5ddd": "/ershoufang/qianchuan/",
    "\u524d\u8fdb\u6c5f\u6c49": "/ershoufang/qianjinjianghan/",
    "\u534e\u79d1\u5927": "/ershoufang/huakeda/",
    "\u5353\u5200\u6cc9": "/ershoufang/zhuodaoquan/",
    "\u5357\u6e56\u6c83\u5c14\u739b": "/ershoufang/nanhuwoerma/",
    "\u53e4\u7530": "/ershoufang/gutian/",
    "\u53f0\u5317\u9999\u6e2f\u8def": "/ershoufang/taibeixiangganglu/",
    "\u540e\u5b98\u6e56": "/ershoufang/houguanhu/",
    "\u540e\u6e56": "/ershoufang/houhu/",
    "\u5434\u5bb6\u5c71": "/ershoufang/wujiashan/",
    "\u5510\u5bb6\u58a9": "/ershoufang/tangjiadun/",
    "\u56db\u65b0": "/ershoufang/sixin/",
    "\u56e2\u7ed3\u5927\u9053": "/ershoufang/tuanjiedadao/",
    "\u5824\u89d2": "/ershoufang/dijiao/",
    "\u5854\u5b50\u6e56": "/ershoufang/tazihu/",
    "\u5927\u667a\u8def": "/ershoufang/dazhilu/",
    "\u5b97\u5173": "/ershoufang/zongguan/",
    "\u5b9d\u4e30\u5d07\u4ec1": "/ershoufang/baofengchongren/",
    "\u5c06\u519b\u8def": "/ershoufang/jiangjunlu/",
    "\u5e38\u9752\u82b1\u56ed": "/ershoufang/changqinghuayuan/",
    "\u5e38\u9752\u8def": "/ershoufang/changqinglu/",
    "\u5e99\u5c71": "/ershoufang/miaoshan/",
    "\u5f90\u4e1c": "/ershoufang/xudong/",
    "\u6587\u5316\u5927\u9053": "/ershoufang/wenhuadadao/",
    "\u65b0\u534e\u8def\u4e07\u8fbe": "/ershoufang/xinhualuwanda/",
    "\u65b0\u5357\u6e56": "/ershoufang/xinnanhu/",
    "\u65b0\u6d32\u5176\u5b83": "/ershoufang/xinzhouqita/",
    "\u6768\u56ed": "/ershoufang/yangyuan/",
    "\u6768\u6c4a\u6e56": "/ershoufang/yangchahu/",
    "\u695a\u6cb3\u6c49\u8857": "/ershoufang/chuhehanjie/",
    "\u6b66\u5e7f\u4e07\u677e\u56ed": "/ershoufang/wuguangwansongyuan/",
    "\u6b66\u660c\u706b\u8f66\u7ad9": "/ershoufang/wuchanghuochezhan/",
    "\u6b66\u6e56": "/ershoufang/wuhu/",
    "\u6c11\u65cf\u5927\u9053": "/ershoufang/minzudadao/",
    "\u6c34\u679c\u6e56": "/ershoufang/shuiguohu/",
    "\u6c49\u5357\u5176\u5b83": "/ershoufang/hannanqita/",
    "\u6c49\u53e3\u5317": "/ershoufang/hankoubei/",
    "\u6c49\u6b63\u8857": "/ershoufang/hanzhengjie/",
    "\u6c5f\u590f\u5176\u5b83": "/ershoufang/jiangxiaqita/",
    "\u6c8c\u53e3": "/ershoufang/dunkou/",
    "\u6c99\u6e56": "/ershoufang/shahu/",
    "\u6d2a\u5c71\u5176\u5b83": "/ershoufang/hongshanqita/",
    "\u738b\u5bb6\u6e7e": "/ershoufang/wangjiawan/",
    "\u73de\u72ee\u5357\u8def": "/ershoufang/luoshinanlu/",
    "\u767d\u6c99\u6d32": "/ershoufang/baishazhou/",
    "\u767e\u6b65\u4ead": "/ershoufang/baibuting/",
    "\u76d8\u9f99\u57ce": "/ershoufang/panlongcheng/",
    "\u79ef\u7389\u6865": "/ershoufang/jiyuqiao/",
    "\u7eb8\u574a": "/ershoufang/zhifang/",
    "\u8001\u5357\u6e56": "/ershoufang/laonanhu/",
    "\u80b2\u624d\u82b1\u6865": "/ershoufang/yucaihuaqiao/",
    "\u8521\u7538\u5176\u5b83": "/ershoufang/caidianqita/",
    "\u8521\u7538\u57ce\u533a": "/ershoufang/caidianchengqu/",
    "\u85cf\u9f99\u5c9b": "/ershoufang/canglongdao/",
    "\u864e\u6cc9\u6768\u5bb6\u6e7e": "/ershoufang/huquanyangjiawan/",
    "\u8857\u9053\u53e3": "/ershoufang/jiedaokou/",
    "\u91d1\u878d\u6e2f": "/ershoufang/jinronggang/",
    "\u91d1\u94f6\u6e56": "/ershoufang/jinyinhu/",
    "\u949f\u5bb6\u6751": "/ershoufang/zhongjiacun/",
    "\u957f\u4e30\u5e38\u7801\u5934": "/ershoufang/changfengchangmatou/",
    "\u957f\u6e2f\u8def": "/ershoufang/changganglu/",
    "\u9633\u903b": "/ershoufang/yangluo/",
    "\u96c6\u8d24": "/ershoufang/jixian2/",
    "\u9752\u5c71": "/ershoufang/qingshan1/",
    "\u9996\u4e49": "/ershoufang/shouyi/",
    "\u9ec4\u57d4\u6c38\u6e05": "/ershoufang/huangpuyongqing/",
    "\u9ec4\u9642\u5176\u5b83": "/ershoufang/huangbeiqita/"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly I'm searching for.

Comment: I ask a new question based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66847985/crawler-detailed-data-based-json-format-file-in-python